# update progress for ASP:Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to use show a "Loading Image" on the click of server side button, that should be unloaded after the button event completes.

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updateprogress-control/
have to use Javascript in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#btnChange').click(function (event) {
     if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
     else event.returnValue = false;
     var dto = { 'id': value };
     //Webservice call started
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        url: ".......",
        data: JSON.stringify(dto),//you need json2.min.js for JSON.stringify() method
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#imageid').attr('src', '../images/load.gif');
            //Show Loading Image which will show the progress
        },
        success: function (msg) {

            //When Successfully completed
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
           //when error occurs     
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ASP.NET Ajax UpdateProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx) control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UdpFormPanel" runat="server >
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" DynamicLayout="true" runat="server"
             AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UdpFormPanel" DisplayAfter="0" >
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="progress">
            <asp:Image ID="ImgProgress" runat="server" 
               ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader-arrows.gif" 
               ToolTip="loading..." />&nbsp;please wait...
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
         ..............
```

This is an examplary progress-class:

```
.progress
{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: absolute;
  left: 44%;
  top: 40%;
  border-style:outset;
  border-color:silver;
  background-color:Silver;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding:5px;
}
```